# Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with firefoxdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with firefoxdriver?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the UA (User Agent) string the website will have to be very crafty to pick on minute details and identify your software. Damn even curl can pass for a Safari web browser.

Comment: I used firefoxdriver this morning. At first it was ok, where no captcha verification appeared. After several minites, there appeared captcha verification  window. However, when I manually opened the google scholar, no verification is needed. So is it  detected by user agent, calculating the frequency?

Comment: Yes, frequency is frequently used to find scrapers. There are tools on Linux that can predict that out of the box like fail2ban. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179477/how-does-fail2ban-detect-the-time-of-an-intrusion-attempt-if-the-log-files-dont